# Sorting After Reducing Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have a set of data that I've parsed from a JSON file that I've reduced down to the number of occurrences. I now need to sort the number of occurrences from most occurrences to least occurrences. As an example:

```
var myData = [{
        "datapoint1": "55",
        "datapoint2": "500",
        "datapoint3": "mydata@data.com",
        "datapoint4": 5656
    }, {
        "datapoint1": "55",
        "datapoint2": "404",
        "datapoint3": "mydata2@data.com",
        "datapoint4": 5656
    }, {
        "datapoint1": "55",
        "datapoint2": "502",
        "datapoint3": "mydata3@data.com",
        "datapoint4": 5656324
    }, {
        "datapoint1": "55",
        "datapoint2": "500",
        "datapoint3": "mydata33@data.com",
        "datapoint4": 5656554
    }
]
```

Then I've taken JSON and parsed, mapped and then reduced to number of each datapoint 2 occurrence. For the sake of brevity, the dummy data above repeats 5-6 thousand times.

```
var dataParsed = JSON.parse(myData);
var mapDataPoint2 = dataParsed.map(function (data) {
    return data.datapoint2
});

var reduceDatapoint2 = mapDataPoint2.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
    prev[cur] = (prev[cur] || 0) + 1;
    return prev;
}, {});

console.log(reduceDatapoint2)
```

At this point I can get the output to console log the number of each occurrence. I now need to be able to sort through from most to least. I've tried .sort() and 
can't seem to get to do anything, no errors in console.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to sort the data by the amount of times the `datapoint2` has had the same value?

Comment: @JacquesMarais - that is correct! EDIT: I want to sort how many times each datapoint2 occurs. So an example: if 500 occurs 17 times,  502 occurs 13 times and 404 occured 7 times, then I want to sort it with 500, then 502, then 404.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the values from your `reduceDatapoint2` to do the sort:

```
myData.sort((a,b) => reduceDatapoint2[b.datapoint2] - reduceDatapoint2[a.datapoint2]);
```

DEMO

```js
var myData = [{
    "datapoint1": "55",
    "datapoint2": "500",
    "datapoint3": "mydata@data.com",
    "datapoint4": 5656
  },
  {
    "datapoint1": "55",
    "datapoint2": "404",
    "datapoint3": "mydata2@data.com",
    "datapoint4": 5656
  },
  {
    "datapoint1": "55",
    "datapoint2": "502",
    "datapoint3": "mydata3@data.com",
    "datapoint4": 5656324
  },
  {
    "datapoint1": "55",
    "datapoint2": "500",
    "datapoint3": "mydata33@data.com",
    "datapoint4": 5656554
  }
]

var dataParsed = myData;
var mapDataPoint2 = dataParsed.map(function(data) {
  return data.datapoint2
});

var reduceDatapoint2 = mapDataPoint2.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  prev[cur] = (prev[cur] || 0) + 1;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(reduceDatapoint2)

myData.sort((a, b) => reduceDatapoint2[b.datapoint2] - reduceDatapoint2[a.datapoint2]);
console.log(myData);
```

Comment: I'd like to clarify my request further. I want to sort how many times each datapoint2 occurs. So an example: if 500 occurs 17 times, 502 occurs 13 times and 404 occurred 7 times, then I want to sort it with 500 first because it occurred the most, then 502, then 404.